# How to use Patch in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver

I have got a patch which supports Nvarchar and Nchar types when we need to publish sql server table to Geoserver. But I dont know, How to use this patch OR where i put this patch so that it can work with Geoserver ?

Can anybody explain, how i use this patch with Geoserver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the GeoServer user-list:

> The basic way under Linux systems is
>   to save the patch file on the file
>   system and apply it using "path -p0 <
>   file.patch", or if the patch has been
>   generated with git, "patch -p1 <
>   file.patch", normally from the root of
>   the GeoServer checkout.
>
> The patch command is available also
>   under Windows, just search for it.
>
> Other tools can apply patches too. For
>   example if you have the set of
>   projects loaded in Eclipse you can
>   apply a patch using "Team/apply patch"
>   and point it to the file.